# NPM : how to deal with seemingly conflicting dependencies?

Tags: javascript, node.js, angular, npm

After running npm I am getting what seems to be conflicting dependency requirements.

For instance, for uglifyjs-webpack-plugin@0.4.6, webpack is required to be ^1.9 || ^2 || ^2.1.0-beta || ^2.2.0-rc || ^3.0.0 while for webpack-dev-middleware@3.7.2  it must be a higher version (^4.0.0)

My newbie questions are

1. I am correct in assuming that there may not be a common version that fits all the requirements?
2. In case 1) is true, how to deal with this (seemingly) conflicting requirements? What is the best practice?

```
npm WARN optional SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: fsevents@~2.3.1 (node_modules\chokidar\node_modules\fsevents):
npm WARN notsup SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: Unsupported platform for fsevents@2.3.2: wanted {"os":"darwin","arch":"any"} (current: {"os":"win32","arch":"x64"})
npm WARN optional SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: fsevents@^1.2.7 (node_modules\watchpack-chokidar2\node_modules\chokidar\node_modules\fsevents):
npm WARN notsup SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: Unsupported platform for fsevents@1.2.13: wanted {"os":"darwin","arch":"any"} (current: {"os":"win32","arch":"x64"})
npm WARN optional SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: fsevents@^1.2.7 (node_modules\webpack-dev-server\node_modules\chokidar\node_modules\fsevents):
npm WARN notsup SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: Unsupported platform for fsevents@1.2.13: wanted {"os":"darwin","arch":"any"} (current: {"os":"win32","arch":"x64"})
npm WARN optional SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: fsevents@^1.2.7 (node_modules\@ionic\app-scripts\node_modules\chokidar\node_modules\fsevents):
npm WARN notsup SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: Unsupported platform for fsevents@1.2.13: wanted {"os":"darwin","arch":"any"} (current: {"os":"win32","arch":"x64"})
npm WARN optional SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: fsevents@~2.3.1 (node_modules\@ionic\app-scripts\node_modules\watchpack\node_modules\chokidar\node_modules\fsevents):
npm WARN notsup SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: Unsupported platform for fsevents@2.3.2: wanted {"os":"darwin","arch":"any"} (current: {"os":"win32","arch":"x64"})
npm WARN ajv-keywords@3.5.2 requires a peer of ajv@^6.9.1 but none is installed. You must install peer dependencies yourself.
npm WARN @angular-devkit/build-webpack@0.1102.8 requires a peer of webpack@^4.6.0 but none is installed. You must install peer dependencies yourself.
npm WARN @ngtools/webpack@11.2.8 requires a peer of webpack@^4.0.0 but none is installed. You must install peer dependencies yourself.
npm WARN webpack-dev-middleware@3.7.2 requires a peer of webpack@^4.0.0 but none is installed. You must install peer dependencies yourself.
npm WARN dotenv-webpack@1.8.0 requires a peer of webpack@^1 || ^2 || ^3 || ^4 but none is installed. You must install peer dependencies yourself.
npm WARN tslint-eslint-rules@4.1.1 requires a peer of tslint@^5.0.0 but none is installed. You must install peer dependencies yourself.
npm WARN uglifyjs-webpack-plugin@0.4.6 requires a peer of webpack@^1.9 || ^2 || ^2.1.0-beta || ^2.2.0-rc || ^3.0.0 but none is installed. You must install peer dependencies yourself.
```

Comment: NPM would usually install peers in `node_modules/PACKAGE1/node_modules/webpack` and `node_modules/PACKAGE2/node_modules/webpack`. For some reason, the package marks them as to be manually installed..